# Magento 2.3: temando.CRITICAL: "accountID" is required. Enter and try again

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, error, exception, critical

I update Magento 2.2.6 to 2.3.1 and I have this error in which I didn't find any information :

> temando.CRITICAL: "accountId" is required. Enter and try again.
>   {"exeption": "[object]
>   (Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException(code: 0): \"accountId\"
>   is required. Enter and try again. at
>   /var/www/site/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Exception/InputException.php:91"}[]

I have already tried :

```
-composer.phar update (in magento root)  
-remove -rf var/* generated/* cache/*  
-php bin/magento setup:upgrade  
-php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f  
-php bin/magento setup:di:compile  
-sudo -R chmod 777 (in magento root for localhost)
```

I didn't find anything about this mistake, do someone had the same and solved it ?
Thank you in advance.

PS: in Case of minus please let me know why so that I could improve my post.

Comment: Are you using Timando shipping on your website?

Comment: @Sumit I suppose yes in config.php I have temando_shipping => 1; but as an extension in vendor/* it should have been updated in same time than magento with composer.phar update, no ?

Comment: OK, are you using this on your website, I mean shipping methods of temando_shipping?

Comment: @Sumit, It's present in composer.lock, magento_prod.sql and in config.php according to the search of VScode

Comment: I think you've not configured the temando_shipping on your website. Please give a try with my answer.

Comment: step to reprocedure  the error when this error come

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***Please run the below commands and try again:***

```
php bin/magento module:disable Temando_Shipping
rm -rf var/cache/ generated/code pub/static/frontend pub/static/adminhtml
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/
```

> Edit

Also, remove the `Temando_Shipping` attributes added in the attribute set after disabling the module else Magento throws an error on the admin product edit form.

> Update

By upgrading to `Magento 2.3.5p1`, the `Temando_Shipping` module will be removed automatically from the Magento.

Comment: Is there any way to fix this issue instead of disabling the extension?

Comment: You shouldn't delete the entire ./generated folder because there is a .htaccess file thats needed. You should just delete ./generated/code/ folder.

Comment: @JaredChu It is a best practice to disable the module which is not used on your website.

Comment: You also need to remove the ts_ attributes from any attribute set being used.

Comment: If you're using nginx the .htaccess is useless and you can safely delete it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch PHP to 7.2, Magento 2.3.1 is running on PHP 7.2, you could use something like Valet plus to manage php versions.

Here is a very good step by step guide to install Valet+

https://davemacaulay.com/the-easiest-way-to-install-magento-2-on-macos-using-valet-plus/

Comment: I think this is the most accurate answer.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the error without disabling the module remove source_model ts_packaging_id

via sql

```
UPDATE `eav_attribute` SET `source_model` = null WHERE `eav_attribute`.`attribute_code` = 'ts_packaging_id';
```

or via an UpgradeSchema.php (replace namespace and increment module version in module.xml)

```
<?php
namespace XXX\YYY\Setup;


    class UpgradeSchema implements \Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface{
    /**
     * Eav setup factory
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function upgrade(\Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface $setup, \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<')) {
            $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create();

            $id = $eavSetup->getAttributeId(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                'ts_packaging_id'
            );
            $eavSetup->updateAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                $id,
                'source_model',
                null
            );
        }
    }
}
```